# XPath query returns blank value

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

I have this HTML snippet:

```
<td class="alt1 icon smallfont" align="center">
    <div class="cal_imp_high" title="High Impact Expected"/>
</td>
```

And Iam trying to get the class value of inside div which is **cal_imp_high** using this XPath query:

```
$xpath->query('//td[@class="alt1 icon smallfont"]/div[@class]/@class');
```

But it displays nothing and I cannot figure out whats wrong..Please someone help me.

Best Regards.

Comment: Is this what they call racial profiling ?

Comment: @adeneo i was just about to edit it ... :-)

Comment: Returning only **black** values ???

Comment: pardon for the misspelled word..thank you for the edit

Comment: now do not attack the poor white space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You XPath query works fine for me.

```
<?php
echo phpversion(), "\n";
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml( <<< eox
<td class="alt1 icon smallfont" align="center">
    <div class="cal_imp_high" title="High Impact Expected"/>
</td>
eox
);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach( $xpath->query('//td[@class="alt1 icon smallfont"]/div[@class]/@class') as $n ) {
    echo 'class: ', $n->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

output:

```
5.4.7
class: cal_imp_high
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your td element is actually in a namespace? Is there an xmlns="...." declaration somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i am just scrapping a website. Is there a solution for this, if namespace is my problem here?

Comment: Search for "XPath default namespace" and you will find a million answers to this question.